# KML track with extra data to each point

Tags: google-maps, kml

where can I find an example for a kml file that has one track, and each point has a special data related to it?

something like:

```
<Placemark>
    <Point>
        <name>Spot 2</name>
        <description>12 May 2011, 2.3g nugget</description>
        <coordinates>144.253,-36.6632,0</coordinates>
    </Point>
    <Point>
        <name>Spot 3</name>
        <description>6 June 2011, 5.6g nugget</description>
        <coordinates>144.2891,-36.6894,0</coordinates>
    </Point>
    <Point>
        <name>Spot 5</name>
        <description>28 June 2011, 4.1g nugget</description>
        <coordinates>144.2344,-36.6907,0</coordinates>
    </Point>
</Placemark>
```

(The problem with the example above is that these points aren't related as a part of one track by google maps)

Comment: That KML doesn't look valid to me, have you looked at the [KML Reference](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#placemark)?

Comment: I did, but I couldnt find what I needed - a track , that for each point in the track I can add more data (such as description)

Comment: [This](https://maps.google.com/maps?q=http:%2F%2Fwww.geocodezip.com%2Fgeoxml3_test%2FSO_KML_MultiPointPlacemark.kml&hl=en&ll=-36.676955,144.261732&spn=0.057479,0.111494&geocode=+&t=m&z=14) is the only way I can think of to do it in KML (someone else may have a better suggestion).

Comment: @ geocodezip - can you please providethe source file?

Comment: Its location is in the link provided.

Comment: thanks but this isn't what I need: I need unique description for each point.. here you just put all the points together.

Comment: I know what you want.  I don't think you can do it with KML on Google Maps (other than how I did it, but I could be wrong).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `<ExtendedData>` to store additional data corresponding to each point in `<gx:Track>`.

If you need actual text data to be available at each coordinate, I'd recommend first creating a `<gx:Track>` and then for each coordinate in the track, creating a Placemark with a `<Point>` with a `<description>` tag.

Also, your KML is incorrect.  The `<name>` and `<description>` tags must go outside of the `<Point>`, inside the `<Placemark>`.  Additionally, you can only have 1 name and 1 description per Placemark, so you'll need to break your KML into multiple Placemarks if you desire separate descriptions and names.

It should look like this:

```
<Placemark>
  <name>Spot 2</name>
  <description>12 May 2011, 2.3g nugget</description>
  <Point>
    <coordinates>144.253,-36.6632,0</coordinates>
  </Point>
</Placemark>

<Placemark>
  <name>Spot 3</name>
  <description>6 June 2011, 5.6g nugget</description>
  <Point>
    <coordinates>144.2891,-36.6894,0</coordinates>
  </Point>
</Placemark>

<Placemark>
  <name>Spot 5</name>
  <description>28 June 2011, 4.1g nugget</description>
  <Point>    
    <coordinates>144.2344,-36.6907,0</coordinates>
  </Point>
</Placemark>
```